# Are these categories considered nominal or ordinal?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

Companies in my dataset can choose to decrease, sustain or increase spending on product X.

If these were ordinal, it would imply that increase is > sustain which is > decrease.

But, is this really considered ordinal? Because unlike GPA, where 4.0 is > 3.9, increasing spending on product X might not be a good thing (e.g. it could be a bad product).

So, my question: is categorising something as ordinal to do with whether something is higher than something else (more money spent on product X), or is it to do with whether something is objectively better than something else?

Comment: I think most people would be willing to treat GPA as a quantitative variable to begin with - not categorical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ordinal categorical variable is a variable that has intrinsic monotonic relations among all its levels/stages. For example, when describing temperature using words 'hot, cold, warm, freezing', they have an order of 'hot, warm, cold, freezing'. It doesn't matter what is their effect on the dependent variable.
In your case, 'increase, sustain, decrease' has an obvious order. It doesn't matter what's their effect on product X. They can affect X in a monotonic way or even a more complex way. It doesn't matter. As long as you can find monotonic order among all levels, it is an ordinal categorical variable.

Comment: One way to put it: 'monotone effect